# Avoid automatic deletion of meeting requests after accepting them

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

How do I tell Outlook not to automatically delete meeting requests after accepting them?

Comment: I wish there was a way to do this via Outlook Web Access http://superuser.com/questions/254454

Comment: Solution is to quit using email

Answer (score 13, accepted):

File → Options → Mail → Send Messages → [ ] "Delete meeting requests and notifications from Inbox after responding"