# Prevent Outlook from automatically deleting meeting emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, outlook-web-access

I'm using Outlook Web Access to read my email. When I receive a meeting notice and acknowledge it, Outlook adds it to my calendar then deletes the email. Is there a way to disable Outlook automatically deleting the meeting email?

There doesn't seem to be any way to configure this in Options - Messaging and Options - Calendar. Note that I'm using Outlook Web Access and not the desktop client.

From the copyright date this appears to be Outlook 2007.

**Follow-up**: Based on edusysadmin's comment I logged-in using IE8, which exposed a setting not available in Firefox - "*Move out-of-date meeting requests and responses to the Deleted Items folder*". However unchecking this box doesn't seem to impact the auto-delete behavior.

**Follow-up 2**: Keep in mind I am using Outlook Web Access via a web browser. I do not have the thick client Outlook installed.

Comment: The available options in Outlook Web Access have nothing to do with the Outlook client, but the version of Exchange implemented.  Depending on the Exchange version it may also depend on what browser you're using too as some browsers cannot see all the option menus.

Comment: While I don't have an answer for you, I'm intrigued to know why you want to do this. Are you aware that if you want to change your mind (for example decline a meeting you already accepted) you can do this by opening the meeting item in your calendar and using the options there to respond, just as with the original request? Of course, this does not allow you to accept something that was declined, since that won't be in your calendar.

Comment: @AdamV, the problem is then I have to manually search through my calendar just to find it. And like you said, if it's declined then it's no longer there. The auto-delete feature is just lame. And not exposing the configuration for it in OWA is even lamer.

Comment: I wonder if in OWA one can create a rule for "Check messages when they arrive", select the condition "is a meeting invitation or update", and as action move it to a new folder. If this works, the downside is needing to access this folder to respond to the request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep Outlook Invitations in Inbox](http://superuser.com/questions/276527/keep-outlook-invitations-in-inbox)

Comment: DURRRRRRRRRRRR... You accepted the meeting invitation? How about I **DELETE** that email so you can't look at it **ever again**! Anything to help you never see your meeting details again! DURRRRRRRRRRRRRRR

Answer (score 57):

In Outlook 2013 and 2016 (Office 365), this is under Options -> Mail -> under "Send messages":

```
Delete meeting requests and notifications from Inbox after responding.
```

It seems trivial but takes long time to find it.

Please see the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Perfect for 2013!

Comment: What a stupid feature. When I accept an invitation, I usually want to re-read the details. Instead Outlook completely deletes it from my inbox.

Comment: This answer works in most cases (thanks!), but I found that the invitation mail is still deleted from Inbox when I send an invitation and add myself in CC. Not sure if there's a different setting for this.

Comment: Question asks about OWA but this is for the desktop client.

Answer (score 18):

In Outlook Web Access(OWA), Under

```
Options -> Calendar Options
```

Uncheck the following checkboxes:

- Automatically place new meeting requests on my calendar, marked Tentative
- Move out-of-date meeting requests and responses to the Deleted Items folder

Comment: Thanks. This led me to the correct setting.  In newer versions it is `Options->See All Options->Settings->Calendar->Delete meeting requests and responses that have been updated`

Comment: @tstaylor7 when you say newer versions, can you provide a range of versions? If you can tell me that I will update my answer.

Comment: `Help->About` gives me `Version: 14.3.210.2` and `Client Access server version: 14.3.123.0`. I'm not sure which is the relevant one or when the change was made.  I'm just a lowly end user, in this case.

Comment: @tstaylor7 Is that 2007, 2010, 2013?

Comment: According to [this page](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/240.exchange-server-and-update-rollups-build-numbers.aspx "Exchange Server and Update Rollups Build Numbers"), it is `Update Rollup 7 for Exchange Server 2010 SP3`.

Comment: So that I don't ask the exact same question again, is there a way to update this? Outlook356 on the web has completely different settings in 2020. What's the proper Stack Exchange protocol for extremely old questions and the hot mess of Versions that makes of MS Office?

Comment: ***Calendar Options***... Oh... Because I wasn't using my **Calendar** when this happened... Figures though: terrible feature, terrible configuration setting organization; should have expected that one.

Comment: Now it's what @tstaylor7 said but there's an added `Events and Invitations` after `Calendar`.

Answer (score 14):

In Outlook 2007 (not sure about other versions), go to

```
Tools -> Options -> E-mail Options -> Advanced E-mail Options
```

Uncheck

> "Delete meeting request from Inbox
>   when responding"

(3rd from the bottom)

Comment: I can't find that option in Outlook Web Access (even when using IE8).

Comment: Ah, it seems it is only available in the Outlook desktop app. Perhaps if you configure it using the desktop client the setting will propagate to the OWA?

Comment: Thanks but I don't have the Desktop app. I'm on a Mac and Outlook isn't free. $280 (for Office) isn't worth it to just to toggle this setting.

Comment: visual answer [here](http://superuser.com/questions/276527/keep-outlook-invitations-in-inbox)

Comment: Should specify what version of Outlook (2007?) these instructions were for, as this no longer applies to Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 3):

An update for more current OWA (Outlook Web Access). Go to

> Settings -> Calendar -> Events and invitations

and deselect

- "Delete Invitations and responses that have been updated" and
- "Delete notifications about forwarded events".

Comment: These are deselected, but it still deleted the emails for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from OWA.

Click "Options" in the upper right corner.
Click "Calendar Options" in the left scrolling list.
Uncheck "Move out-of-date meeting requests and responses to the Deleted Items folder" in the "Automatic Calendar Processing" section of the options.

Hope that works for you.

(I'm using OWA 8.4.106.1 with IE8).

Comment: Sorry, just noticed your addendum that this didn't work for you. I'll assume that you saved your change to the prefs and that it took. Is it possible that a mobile device is syncing with your account and also doing the delete?

Comment: There are no other clients synced with my account .I just verified and I do have "Move out-of-date meeting requests and responses to the Deleted Items folder" unselected. I accepted a meeting notice and the meeting email is still automatically deleted.

Comment: All that does is automatically delete a meeting request if the time window has already passed.

Answer (score 1):

Also enable the following in the Mail section of the Outlook options:

> Update tracking information, and then delete responses that don't contain comments

[image]

Comment: @JosephA, it wasn't just an image at the time you commented?