# Keep Outlook Invitations in Inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a setting so that when an Outlook meeting invitation is accepted the invitation is not automatically removed from the Inbox?  I often accept invitations and then realize that I needed some information about them.  It would make it easier if they stayed in the Inbox and behaved more like everything else in the Inbox.

Comment: What about Outlook for macOS?

Comment: What about Outlook Mobile ?

Comment: This question seems a duplicate of [Prevent Outlook from automatically deleting meeting emails](https://superuser.com/questions/254454/prevent-outlook-from-automatically-deleting-meeting-emails)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it's a configurable option in Outlook.

### Outlook 2003 and 2007

1. Go to:

   - Tools > Options > Advanced E-mail Options (**Outlook 2003**)
   - Tools > Options > E-mail Options > Advanced E-mail Options (**Outlook 2007**)
2. Untick *Delete meeting request from Inbox when responding*.

   [image: 2003/2007 screenshot]

### Outlook 2010, 2013 and 2016

1. Go to the File tab in the ribbon and click Options. Select the Mail entry in the left pane.
2. Scroll down and untick *Delete Meeting Requests and Notifications from Inbox after Responding*.

   [image: 2016 screenshot]

Now when you accept a meeting invitation it should keep the original mail in the inbox.

Comment: I used your phrase "Delete meeting request from inbox when responding" to find this solution for Outlook 2010: http://www.officeusers.org/editorials/default.aspx?id=2770

Comment: Ah, apologies, I forgot that things moved about in 2010 because of the ribbon. I'll edit the answer above to include 2010 details as well.

Answer (score 4):

On Outlook online, go to Options -> All Options -> Settings -> Calendar, then uncheck "Delete meeting requests and responses that have been updated" then press save.

Comment: Did not find that option on office.com in 2022. This *might* be the same option: All settings -> Calendar -> Events and invitations -> Delete invitations and responses that have been updated.