# Prevent removal of invites from OSX Outlook

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2011

Is there a setting so that when an Outlook **for Mac** meeting invitation is accepted the invitation is not automatically removed from the Inbox ***in Outlook for Mac 2011***? I often accept invitations and then realize that I needed some information about them. It would make it easier if they stayed in the Inbox and behaved more like everything else in the Inbox.

Comment: I admit, the question is the same as [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/276527/keep-outlook-invitations-in-inbox), but this is for OSX (which has a different menu system) instead of for Windows.

Comment: It is automatically *deleted*, in case anyone wants to know. Because, you know, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is setting up a rule to copy incoming meeting invites to a folder, making them easily available:

- Create a folder, for example "meetings", and synchronize (send/receive) so folder is on server.
- Add a custom rule / filter:

  - If type is a meeting invite: Copy message to the folder
  - Also using a second action "mark unread" can make things look cleaner