# Prevent Outlook 2016 from deleting event invite emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, inbox

When I respond to an event invitation in Outlook 2016 (installed on my PC), it automatically moves the corresponding email to the `Deleted` folder. I would like to prevent this.

I found similar questions asked on this site:

- [Prevent Outlook from automatically deleting meeting emails](https://superuser.com/questions/254454/prevent-outlook-from-automatically-deleting-meeting-emails)
- [Keep Outlook Invitations in Inbox](https://superuser.com/questions/276527/keep-outlook-invitations-in-inbox)

I followed the provided solutions and have the option `Delete meeting requests and notifications from Inbox after responding` turned off.

However, my Outlook still deleted the event invitation emails every time I respond to them which means I manually have to move them back to the `Inbox` folder.

If anyone has encountered this issue and has a solution, I would be happy to hear it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only option I know could control the meeting invitation deletion behavior is what you have mentioned: Delete meeting requests and notifications from Inbox after responding. According on my testing, when this option is unchecked, the meeting invitation should be deleted after responding. Maybe you can try creating a new Outlook mail profile and set up your email account in the new profile, and then see whether this issue continues.

Besides, if possible, try set up the email account on another computer and see whether the issue follows the account.

Comment: Do you mean that the meeting invitation should **not** be deleted if the option is unchecked?

Unfortunately this is my work email on my work computer, but I see what I can do from your suggestions.