# Outlook invites being deleted

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I send invites through Outlook.  Some of the people do not use the Calendar feature and are not the most tech savvy.  When they accept the invite the email goes away.  Is there a way to set it on my end so the email doesn't go away.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1267239/prevent-outlook-2016-from-deleting-event-invite-emails

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/276527/keep-outlook-invitations-in-inbox

Comment: Send them a regular email instead of an invite.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, this thread is not duplicated with the above links as OP is seeking options on the meeting organizers' side.

As far as I know, it is the setting on the recipients' side ("Delete meeting requests and notifications from Inbox after responding.")that controls whether the meeting requests will be removed from the Inbox after responding. So I am afraid there is no way on the organizer's end to control this behavior.

As an workaround, you may refer to the comment of Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 to send a regular email in addition to the meeting request.

Or you may train the users to uncheck the option via File > Options > Mail > Delete meeting requests and notifications from Inbox after responding:

(Note: This works for all meeting requests received by the user.)
[image]

Besides, if your purpose is to keep attendees from missing your meeting, you may consider [setting a reminder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-or-remove-reminders-6d3c3e29-59d3-4b6d-a15d-933f166add64) for the meeting so that the recipients will get a pop up alert before the meeting.