# Outlook 2010 automatically deletes meeting request e-mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

This is a continuation of [Prevent Outlook from automatically deleting meeting emails](https://superuser.com/questions/254454/prevent-outlook-from-automatically-deleting-meeting-emails)

which based on my interpretation, did not yield resolution. Tools -> Options -> E-mail Options -> Advanced E-mail Options, "Delete meeting request from Inbox when responding" **is unchecked**, as it should be.

Scenario is as follows (both users are using a locally hosted Exchange server) - User A, using the Outlook 2010 SP1 Windows application, creates a meeting request for User B. User B receives a copy of the request via email and on his smartphone. The e-mail invitation User B received never hits User A's inbox, and is instead in his deleted items folder.

I also found this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrclients/thread/9be3e009-4150-4dc2-809e-a7974b31aac9

and I plan on attempting that later this afternoon. Just curious if anyone else has encountered this. It's...rather bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

Does User A have this option switched on?
File > Options > Mail > Tracking > Update tracking informatiom, and then delete responses that don't contain comments.

If this is ticked and User A receives a meeting response from User B, if the response has no comments in the body and is then marked as "read", the response will be filed in the deleted items folder.  If User A is saying he has never marked the response as "read" and it just goes straight to deleted items, it may be a combination of User A having this option ticked AND having a rule which marks calendar items as "read"....
Hopes this helps

Answer (score 0):

Create a new rule. Each time a meeting request is received, have that rule COPY that meeting request to a special archive folder and, if you like, "Mark it as Read." That way when Outlook deletes the original, you still have the copy, neatly organized into a Meetings folder :)