# O365 - Prevent resource booking attendant moving emails to the deleted items

Tags: office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, exchange-2016

I have a room booking mailbox which was converted from a shared mailbox using `Set-Mailbox` in a Hybrid Exchange environment.

We would like the resource booking attendant and calendar booking attendant to process any meeting requests or appointments (which it does) however without moving the items to the deleted items once processed.

I have looked through `Set-Mailbox` but failed to identify anything that could set this, and I have tried to adjust below the settings in the mailbox however these did not make any difference.

Tried
[Delete meeting requests and notifications from Inbox after responding.](https://superuser.com/a/1058351/761051) and [Update tracking information, and then delete responses that don't contain comments](https://superuser.com/a/804449/761051) to no avail

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: This will most probably take VBA to do. As I don't use O365, I can help theoretically, but the testing and final touches will need to be done by yourself. Is that fine with you?

Answer (score 0):

Try open the room mailbox via OWA and then set the option for it.

[image]

Check the steps in [this link](http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-access-a-resource-mailbox-equipment-or-room-in-owa).

Comment: Neither of those options are selected unfortunately.