# Prevent Outlook 365 OWA in 2020 from automatically deleting meeting emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Previously asked and answered in older versions. No solution for Outlook OWA in 2020. Older instructions don't apply now.

See 
[Prevent Outlook from automatically deleting meeting emails](https://superuser.com/questions/254454/prevent-outlook-from-automatically-deleting-meeting-emails)

Most recent comment to above discussion is copied below, but there's no response to it. 
Also, can't find anything else anywhere on Internet.

•
So that I don't ask the exact same question again, is there a way to update this? Outlook356 on the web has completely different settings in 2020. What's the proper Stack Exchange protocol for extremely old questions and the hot mess of Versions that makes of MS Office? – Chazbot Feb 19 at 2:27

Comment: Anyone looking forward to this feature should upvote on the Microsoft Feedback Portal about this topic.

Prevent Meeting Invite From being Delete
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/711514f5-5453-ed11-a81b-000d3a05a1b3

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try > Settings > View all Outlook settings > Calendar > Events and invitations > Delete invitations and responses that have been updated.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that is already unchecked and it still deletes them.